# Remove save option from Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

Hi I'm using Elasticsearch for dashboard reporting and I'm trying to find where the source code is located for the dashboard so that I can remove the save options located on the upper right hand corner. Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The display of the save button in the upper right hand corner is controlled by a dashboard option. You will not need to touch the source code.

That said, given that you can't easily save the dashboard after having removed the save button, you will need to either create a new dashboard json file or edit an existing one to disable all To Save options.

After creating a dashboard you like, you can export its schema under Loading > Advanced. Edit the json file for your dashboard with any text editor and set all saving options to false in the loader part of the file:

```
  "loader": {
    "save_gist": false,
    "save_elasticsearch": false,
    "save_local": false,
    "save_default": false,
    "save_temp": false,
    "save_temp_ttl_enable": true,
    "save_temp_ttl": "30d",
    "load_gist": false,
    "load_elasticsearch": false,
    "load_elasticsearch_size": 20,
    "load_local": true,
    "hide": true
  }
```

Once that is done, store your dashboard.json file in this folder: https://github.com/elasticsearch/kibana/tree/master/src/app/dashboards

And you'll be able to access it at `http://localhost:9200/index.html#/dashboard/file/dashboard.json`

Here is how to hide it through the Kibana configuration editor:

1. Click on "Configure Dashboard" (top right)

[image]

2. In the Controls tab, uncheck all Save to options

[image]

3. Save your change and the save button will have disapeared.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Linux and found mine in `/var/www/kibana3/app/dashboards`